# C++ time conversion program

Tags: c++

This is an assignment for a class and I have it almost to where I want it just wanting some advice on the best way to proceed.

The user will enter time in a 24 hour format and a delay time in hours and minutes. I must compute and display the time in AM/PM format at the end of the delay. I have to use functions and must not use global variables. I also need to have a condition to quit when 999 is entered for the hours section.

Basically, I am trying to decide the best way to proceed with computing the delay. I've tried a few different methods but, haven't really been happy with any of them. Right now the program simply loops asking for hours, minutes, and delay until I can decide the best way to proceed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void convert(int&, int&, int&, char&);
void output(int&, int&, char&);

int main()
{

    int hours, minutes, delay;
    char ampm; 

    cout<<"Enter the value for Hours (999 to quit):  "<<endl;
    cin >> hours;



    while (hours != 999)
    {
        cout << "Enter minutes: ";
        cin >> minutes;

        cout << "Enter delay: ";
        cin >> delay;

        cout<<"Enter the value for Hours (999 to quit):  "<<endl;
    cin >> hours;


    }
return 0;   
}


void convert(int& hours, int& minutes,  int& delay, char& ampm)
{

    if(hours > 12)
    {
        hours  =  hours - 12;
        ampm = 'p';
    }
    else if(hours  == 12) ampm = 'p'; 
    else ampm = 'a'; 
}


void output(int& hours, int& minutes, char& ampm)
{
    if(ampm == 'p')
    {
        (minutes  < 10); cout << hours << ":0" << minutes << " P.M."; 
         cout << hours << ":" << minutes << " P.M.";
    }
    else
    {
        (minutes < 10); cout << hours << ":0" << minutes << " A.M."; 
         cout << hours << ":" << minutes << " A.M.";
        }

}
```

Comment: Look up the modulo operator, '%', it can be very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps. I have tried to keep it clean and simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void convert(int&, int&, int&, string&);
void output(int&, int&, string&);

int main()
{

    int hours, minutes, delay;
    string ampm;

    cout << "Enter hours(0-24): ";
    cin >> hours;

    do{
        cout << "Enter minutes: ";
        cin >> minutes;

        cout << "Enter delay(in minutes): ";
        cin >> delay;

        convert(hours, minutes, delay, ampm);
        output(hours, minutes, ampm);

        cout << endl << "Enter the value for Hours (999 to quit):  ";
        cin >> hours;
    } while (hours != 999);

    return 0;
}


void convert(int& hours, int& minutes, int& delay, string& ampm)
{
    int temp = 0;

    minutes += delay;
    if (minutes > 60) {
        temp = minutes / 60;
        hours += temp;
        minutes = minutes - temp * 60;
    }

    if (hours > 12){
        hours -= 12;
        ampm = "PM";
    }
    else {
        ampm = "AM";
    }
}


void output(int& hours, int& minutes, string& ampm)
{
    if (minutes > 0 && minutes < 10) {
        cout << hours << ":0" << minutes << " " << ampm << endl;;
    }
    else if (minutes == 0) {
        cout << hours << ":0" << minutes << " " << ampm << endl;;
    }
    else {
        cout << hours << ":" << minutes << " " << ampm << endl;
    }
}
```